# Google Maps, set the center coordinates to be off centered in the container

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The setCenter method focuses on the coordinates at 50:50 height:width of the google maps div. What I want to do is change to center from 50% left to 25% left. Does Google Maps allow this or is there a trick around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) you'll see several methods for the Map element.

Using a script like this (not tested) :

```
var ne = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
var sw = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();

var lat = sw.lat() + 0.5*(ne.lat() - sw.lat());
var long = sw.lng() + 0.25*(ne.lng() - sw.lng());

map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long));
```

you should achieve what you would like to do.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_MarkerWithLabel_25pct.html)

Comment: This will give you 25% from the right, to get it from the left, either switch the order of the longitude values in the delta or use 0.75.